# An internal error occurred during: "Label Job" in Android debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-sdk-tools, android-debug

I am getting this error while single stepping through my Android code:

> An internal error occurred during: "Label Job".
>   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.variables.IndexedVariablePartition
>   cannot be cast to org.eclipse.debug.core.model.IExpression

[image]

This happens when I try to expand an array variable that I am watching, by clicking on the small `+` sign to the left of it. It comes once, and after I click ok, it doesn't come back again, but I cannot see the elements of the array in the watch window. But if I press F5 to continue single step, after this, the error comes back again if I press the `+`sign again. All he variables I am watching are `double` variables. How do I get rid of this?