# Multiple problems have occured, An internal error occured during: "Label job"

Tags: android, eclipse

when I tried to debug my android project, I encountered an error saying:
Multiple problems have occured, An internal error occured during: "Label job"
this is a picture for better understanding what kind of error is this:
[image]

I don't know what is this about and seems like it's hard to find information about that like this link: [An internal error occurred during: "Label Job" in Android debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421099/an-internal-error-occurred-during-label-job-in-android-debugging)

this is the code I'm trying to execute and I think nothing is wrong with the code:

```
if (!result.equals("Nothing")){
                    String records[] = result.split(PublicVariable.FIELD_SPLITTER);
                    String name;
                    City city= new City(activity);
                    city.empty();
                    for(int i=0;i<records.length;i++){
                        name = records[i];
                        city = new City(activity, name);
                        city.insert();
                    }
                    xLog.info("Cities inserted...");
                }
```

Maybe it's an Eclipse bug.

Comment: its a kinda bug in eclipse.update your eclipse/sdk